# Selector :root in css

Tags: html, css, colors

I am using :root selector to simplify my css.
This is how I use it in css:

```
:root {
 --bg-color: #00AEEF;
 --bg-color-transparent: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 --text-color: #ffffff;
 --bg-color-hover: #008DF8;
 --text-color-hover: #ffffff;
 --border-color: 1px solid #00AEEF;
 --border-color-hover: #A0D6FF;
 --border-color-transparent: 2px solid rgba(0,174,239,0.2);
 --logout-footer-bg: #ffffff;
 --logout-footer-text: #00AEEF;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: var(--bg-color) 1px solid;
    background: var(--bg-color);
}
table.login-view {
    /* Change the width to work with new changes */
    width: 25%;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: var(--border-color);
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
table.error-message {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: var(--border-color);
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

This is working perfectly in Firefox, but no other browser (mobile and desktop).
My question is that is there any other way to do it that it support all the browsers? if not, is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the `:root` selector, which is supported in all current versions of major browsers. It's with the use of CSS variables, such as `--bg-color`, which are only supported in Firefox right now. See [this page](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables) for more details.

If you want to use variables in CSS and support browsers other than Firefox, you'll need to use a CSS preprocessor like Sass or LESS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is there any alternative way to get the same result?

Comment: Sure. If you want to stick to pure CSS that works across browsers, just remove all variable declarations and plug in the actual values wherever you have `var(--property-name)`. If you want to use variables, use a CSS preprocessor like Sass. [This article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/why-im-excited-about-native-css-variables/) has a fairly in-depth discussion of CSS and CSS-preprocessor variables and the differences between them.